# Unable to click link / webelement using robotframework selenium method using xpath way

Tags: selenium-chromedriver, robotframework

I have following xpath in a frame.

```
<td width="20%" class="datawatchvalue">
<span data-bind="text: iTotal" onclick="window.parent.dashBoardIndexClick( DASH_BOARD_INDEX_TOTAL, 'All' );">6017</span></td>
```

where 6017 represent the LINK, and it' dynamic, 
I have tried multiple method to click the link using xpath method but none of them are working.

Frame html.

```
<div class="middle-north ui-layout-pane ui-layout-pane-north" style="position: absolute; margin: 0px; top: 0px; bottom: auto; left: 0px; right: 0px; width: auto; z-index: 0; height: 208px; display: block; visibility: visible;">
    <div class="ui-widget-header ui-corner-top">Data Watch</div>
    <div class="ui-widget-content">
        <div class="dwtable" id="dwtableid" style="width: 75%">
            <div class="dwrow" style="width: 75%">
                <div class="cell border-right-dashboard" id="topleftid"> 
                    <div class="cell">
```

Here are my tries.

```
Select Frame      middle-north ui-layout-pane ui-layout-pane-north
Click Element    xpath=//[@data-bind="text: iTotal"]



click link   xpath=//*[@data-bind="text: iTotal"]
Click Element  xpath=//*[@title="Open a new Index Window"]
Click Link  xpath=//*[@id="researchtoolbarcolumn"][@title="Open a new Index Window"][@onclick="createAssetWindow('Index')"]
click link  xpath=/html/body/div[1]/div[1]/div/div[1]/table/tbody/tr/td[1]
Click Link  xpath=//*[@id="researchtoolbarcolumn"]
```

Comment: What does "unable" mean? Do you get any errors, or are there no errors but nothing is happening?

Comment: Yes, It's not clicking the link if I used any of the above listed action.

Comment: I am getting error as listed below

Element with locator 'xpath=//span[@data-bind="text: iTotal"]' not found

Comment: One more thing, Not sure will this help , but my link is in the subframe of the page. so do i need to specify anything extra or use different way to click the link?

Comment: If the link is in a frame, you need to switch to that frame. That's a critically important detail to have left out. You should [edit] your question to mention that fact.

Comment: is it working now?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I missed the details to enter the frame part. my bad.

now as per the updated new code above, I am selecting the frame 

But still I am "NOT" able to click the link.

Yday when i replied the post, mistakenly i said "NOW"

sorry about the confusion.

Any help towards thiis really appreciable ..

Comment: @BryanOakley Can you please review the above the comments and suggest us. 
Let us know if you want me to post the entire html of the page.

Comment: Does the above `select frame` work? You appear to be selecting a div in a frame rather than the frame itself.

Comment: Thanks Bryan. When I was using chrome inspect method for the link, the most top level highlighting screen was the above class and I was assuming that is as "Frame"   . While debugging further, I was going 5 level ahead to really determine the what is frame here, then I found the "frame" which happens to be true frame. Now I am able to select and click the dynamic link.   Thanks for your support.

Comment: The solution worked for me is as follows 

    Select Frame  dashboardframe
    Click Element  xpath=//*[@data-bind="text: iClose"]

Answer (score 0):

Try to do it with

```
Click Element    xpath=//span[@data-bind="text: iTotal"]
```

Not `Click Link`, but `Click Element` - the Link keyword limits the scope to only `<a>` elements, while Element executes it on whatever.
And the data-bind value looks the most solid one in the sample html.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. but that didn't help. I am getting following error same like earlier.

2) Element with locator 'xpath=//span[@data-bind="text: iTotal"]' not found.